# How to run MSCK on Hive Standalone Metastore server via thrift client

Tags: hive, partitioning, hadoop-partitioning, hive-metastore

I'm using Hive as my meta store database and the Hive Standalone Metastore for dealing with the DDLs, via [this thrift client](https://github.com/quintoandar/hive-metastore-client) that implements the server thrift mapping.

I want to perform an MSCK (or some other method like this) to bulk add partitions to the Hive new tables.

But afaik, [this Thrift mapping file](https://github.com/apache/hive/blob/branch-3.0/standalone-metastore/src/main/thrift/hive_metastore.thrift) doesn't expose an msck method.
Although, I see that there's something about the Msck implemented [inside standalone server](https://github.com/apache/hive/blob/master/standalone-metastore/metastore-server/src/main/java/org/apache/hadoop/hive/metastore/Msck.java) (I think that it should have been implemented in [jira HIVE-17824](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HIVE-17824)). But there isn't in the HiveMetastore class (that I understood that is the mapping of the Thrift server methods).

Does anyone know whether I can run MSCK through the standalone hive server via thrift client?

Answer (score 0):

With python I am currently using this client with success: [PyHive](https://github.com/dropbox/PyHive).

And from dbeaver you can also do it (if the command must be run by some human): [dbeaver](https://dbeaver.com/docs/wiki/Apache-Hive/).

EDIT (I did not realize that the question was about sending the command directly to hive metastore):

The interface called [IMetaStoreClient](https://github.com/apache/hive/blob/master/standalone-metastore/metastore-common/src/main/java/org/apache/hadoop/hive/metastore/IMetaStoreClient.java) (the protocol between hive client and hive metastore server) does not implement `MSCK` command because it does not need it. Let me explain the logic behind `MSCK` command:

1. Check if table exists in hive metastore.
2. Scan for new partitions in the physical file system where the table stores its data. See code [`checkMetastore`](https://github.com/apache/hive/blob/master/standalone-metastore/metastore-server/src/main/java/org/apache/hadoop/hive/metastore/Msck.java#L133).
3. Create/Add those new partitions. See code [`createPartitionsInBatches`](https://github.com/apache/hive/blob/master/standalone-metastore/metastore-server/src/main/java/org/apache/hadoop/hive/metastore/Msck.java#L225). This code ends up using the method called `add_partitions` of the hive metastore client.

   See [`add_partitions`](https://github.com/apache/hive/blob/master/standalone-metastore/metastore-server/src/main/java/org/apache/hadoop/hive/metastore/Msck.java#L481). **In this point and not before the client application sends data to the hive metastore server**.
4. Drop partitions which are not in the file system anymore. See code [`dropPartitionsInBatches`](https://github.com/apache/hive/blob/master/standalone-metastore/metastore-server/src/main/java/org/apache/hadoop/hive/metastore/Msck.java#L243) which ends up using the method called `dropPartitions` of the hive metastore client.

   See [`dropPartitions`](https://github.com/apache/hive/blob/master/standalone-metastore/metastore-server/src/main/java/org/apache/hadoop/hive/metastore/Msck.java#L568). **Again, it is in this point and not before where the client application sends data to the hive metastore server**.

`MSCK` is not really a hive metastore command. It requires logic implemented by the client running that `MSCK` command. In your case, you should add that logic to the client that you want to use.

For example, Spark, already implements that logic when using `MSCK`.

Comment: I'm connecting through Hive Metastore (without HiveServer). This lib PyHive uses the HiveServer; and with the HiverServer it's possible to run the msck command. The question is how to run via thrift client in the standalone metastore server (port 9083).

Comment: @LucasMendesMotaDaFonseca sorry, I did not realize it was about sending the command directly to hive metastore. I just edited my answer. Hopefully it will be helpful.

Comment: tks for the clarifications. I'm not sure I got it. But I see that this MSCK logic could be implemented natively in the hive metastore server, wdyt? (we'll have the partition commands in the thrift server and the S3 path in the table DDL)

Comment: @LucasMendesMotaDaFonseca clients must implement this interface:  [IMetaStoreClient.java](https://github.com/apache/hive/blob/master/standalone-metastore/metastore-common/src/main/java/org/apache/hadoop/hive/metastore/IMetaStoreClient.java). That interface does not have a method called MSCK. Said in a differente way: the protocol between metastore client and metastore server does not implement the MSCK method.